# Android USB volume name

Tags: macos, usb, mount, android

When I turn on my (Nexus S) Android's USB storage, Mac OS X mounts it as "NO NAME". Among other mounted volumes, it's confusing. How can I give it a more relevant name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to reformat the card.  Once "NO NAME" is mounted, simply select the volume from the left pane of the finder window, right click (or control click) on it, and select "Rename".  This will the highlight the name, allowing you to edit it.  I haven't seen any adverse effects from doing this on my Droid X.

Answer (score -1):

With my Droid X I was able to format the card and rename it. If you decide to go that route, back up everything on the card to make sure you don't lose any data.

Comment: Reformatting is **not** necessary. See above answer.

Comment: will try that when more confident in my skills :P